# Simple Matlab loop creation

Tags: matlab, loops

Good morning,

I have a doubt about a loop. I think it's real simple but I don't get how to do it. I'm going to try to simplify the question.

```
x= [... ; 106; 112; 111]
param=  [1.2 ; 1.5; 1.7]
```

What I need to do is the following. Create three new values, by doing this:

**1st loop:**

```
> y(k) = a1*x(k-1)  - a2*x(k-2)  - a3*x(k-3) 
> y(k) = (1.2*111)+(1.5*112)+( 1.7*106) = 
> y(K) = 481, 4 result of the new value
```

**2nd loop:**

```
   x= [... ; 106; 112; 111; 481,4] % this is the new added value to the vector: 
    y(k) = a1*x(k-1)  - a2*x(k-2)  - a3*x(k-3)
    y(k) = (1.2*481,4)+(1.5 *111)+( 1.7*112) =
    y(K) =         result of the 2 new value
```

The routine consists in using always the param values 'by order' and multiply the x vector using penultimate value, then the antepenultimate and the following. I don't know how to manage it because it has to create three new times.

Any advice would be appreciated! :) Thanks in advance

Comment: The questions is quite vague. What is a1 through a3? What do you with `y(k) = (1.2*111)+(1.5 *112)+( 1.7*106) = y(K) = result of the new value`. Could you also provide a vector `x` that can actually be used, or at the very least describe size or any other information.

Comment: It looks almost like what you are trying to do is a convolution between `x` and a flipped `param` (`conv(x,flip(param))`) or maybe `conv(x,[0; flip(param)])` (since x(k) is skipped). Try and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! JCKaz, a1, a2... ara the param vector (a1= 1.2, a2= 1.5 and a3=1,7). For example: x= [30;41; 71;106;112;111] (but I only need the last 3 values).

Comment: Thanks Florian! I'm going to try it! :)

Comment: How does `k` changes? if `param` has only 3 values, and you only need the last 3 values of `x`, the `y(k)` is always **481.4**. Something is missing here...

Comment: EBH, you are right, I have just edited the post to try to explain it better! Thanks for your comment. Param values are always the same, but the vector is changing.

Comment: How many time you want to calculate this? i.e. what is the size of `y` when this process ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only `y` (or `x`) no need for both, as you just add all `y` in the end of `x`. Here is a simple solution for adding another `N` values:

```
N = 103;
y = zeros(N,1);
y(1:3) = [106 112 111]; % this is the end of your x
param = [1.2 ; 1.5; 1.7];
for k = 4:N
    y(k) = (param(1).*y(k-1))+(param(2).*y(k-2))+(param(3).*y(k-3));
end
```